# Can the playbook execute the order of operation when there are 2 hosts?

Tags: ansible

Can the playbook execution have an order of operation when there are 2 hosts? i.e. on databases it should run only if web servers are done.

Like here:

```yaml
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
 
  tasks:
  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum: name=httpd state=latest
  - name: write the apache config file
    template: src=/srv/httpd.j2 dest=/etc/httpd.conf
 
- hosts: databases
  remote_user: root
 
  tasks:
  - name: ensure postgresql is at the latest version
    yum: name=postgresql state=latest
  - name: ensure that postgresql is started  
    service: name=postgresql state=started
```

I executed it, but it was executed on different machines at the same time.

I can’t find some way to have an order of execution.

Comment: Seems you want control the order within hosts of group `webservers` and `databases`? There are some ways to [control the execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks. Using images  is usually barely readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content, visually impaired people cannot use their voice synthesizer, people trying to help you cannot copy/paste the content if needed, it uses 1000x more data volume than the equivalent text. And above all, it is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take advantage from [Patterns: targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) and [Controlling playbook execution: strategies and more](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html).

If you organise your inventory like

```
[website]
frontend
backend

[frontend:children]
webserver

[backend:children]
databases

[webserver]
web01.example.com
web02.example.com

[databases]
db01.example.com
db02.example.com
```

[linear](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/linear_strategy.html#linear-strategy) execution in groups

```
ansible-inventory --graph
@all:
  |--@backend:
  |  |--@databases:
  |  |  |--db01.example.com
  |  |  |--db02.example.com
  |--@frontend:
  |  |--@webserver:
  |  |  |--web01.example.com
  |  |  |--web02.example.com
  |--@ungrouped:
  |--@website:
  |  |--backend
  |  |--frontend
```

will run the webserver update before the database update.

```
- hosts: website      
  remote_user: root
 
  tasks:

  - name: Ensure Apache HTTPd is at the latest version
    yum: 
      name: httpd 
      state: latest
    when: "'webserver' in group_names"

  - name: Write the Apache HTTPd config file
    template: 
      src: /srv/httpd.j2 
      dest: /etc/httpd.conf
    when: "'webserver' in group_names"
 
  - name: Ensure PostgreSQL is at the latest version
    yum: 
      name: postgresql 
      state: latest
    when: "'databases' in group_names"
```

Also it is possible to apply a run to `frontend`, `backend`, `webserver` or `databases` only.